# How do I stop embedded videos overlapping a fixed position header

Tags: html, css-position

I have embedded several youtube videos on a page with a fixed header and they overlap when scrolling. I do not have this problem with any other content.

I have tried zindex and it does not work with position:fixed elements. Also i have tried typing wmode:transparent into the embed tag and this hasnt worked either

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Please provide the code or a link to the page where this is happening. Without this we can't answer any questions as it could be related to how your site is currently implemented.

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of SO post:<br />
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10554540/1195891

Comment: This is possibly a duplicate of SO post:
http://stackoverflow.com/q/10554540/1195891<br />How ironic, this became duplicated via Human Verification Process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try appending `&wmode=transparent` to the end of your youtube URLs. See if that helps.

** edit:

Use `?wmode=transparent` or `&wmode=transparent` (if the existing url already have name/value parameters and already include '?'). If that does not prevent the issue, then try this jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('iframe').each(function(){
      var url = $(this).attr("src");
      if(url.indexOf("?")>0){
         $(this).attr("src",url+"&wmode=transparent")
      }else{
         $(this).attr("src",url+"?wmode=transparent")
      }
   });
});
</script>
```

NB: the jQuery script is a slightly modified version of the one suggested on this website: http://www.scorchsoft.com/news/youtube-z-index-embed-iframe-fix

Comment: This site has more suggestions, one is to add `?wmode=transparent` and the other is a small jQuery script: [link](http://www.scorchsoft.com/news/youtube-z-index-embed-iframe-fix)
It focuses on embedding YouTube videos via the iframe embed code.