# youtube api , firefox 4.0 . iframe failing to load videos

Tags: javascript, api, video, youtube

Trying to fix this issue with iFrame and Firefox 4.0 failing to load videos
This is currently my code. I have tried to look into this site - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5/Optimizing_Your_Pages_for_Speculative_Parsing for assistance. But It doesn't quite make much sense to me.

Any assistance would be grateful

Regards
Matt

```
<div id="myVid"></div>

        <script>

          var tag = document.createElement('script');
          tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
          var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
          firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


          var player;
          function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('myVid', {
              height: '80%',
              width: '100%',
              events: {
                'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
            });
          }


          function onPlayerReady(event) {
            event.target.playVideo();
          }



          function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
              getVideo();

            }
          }

        </script><
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the YouTube Embed Method requires modern browsers with **HTML5 postMessage** support.

The version of Firefox you are using is version 4.0 but postMessage is available in Firefox starting from **version 6**.

YouTube API Embed Requirements:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Requirements

HTML5 postMessage Reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.postMessage

Coincidentally, if you were using Firefox Version 6 and your embed markup was complete with Video ID, you will be subject to a catastrophic bug that's surfaced the last two days for the YouTube Embed API... Flash Fallback is broken! See this SO workaround solution if applicable to you:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10560802/1195891